# Why is the eigenvector centrality considered a generalized version of degree centrality?

Tags: graph-theory, network

The eigenvector centrality of a vertex in a graph, is a self-referential centrality, which basically says that a vertex with a high value of eigenvector centrality is one that is adjacent to highly eigenvector-central vertices.

From this, how does one infer that it is a more generalized version of degree centrality, where the most central vertices are the ones adjacent to vertices with a high degree? The definition of the eigenvector centrality tells nothing about how degree plays a role.

Comment: This sentence from the Wikipedia article seems relevant: "Restricting consideration to this group [based on counting the number of walks starting from a given vertex] allows for a soft characterization which places centralities on a spectrum from walks of length one (degree centrality) to infinite walks (eigenvalue centrality).[2][5]"